# hide overflow scrollbar on modal

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a modal with a scrollbar.

- The modal has a border-radius of 12px
- The scrollbar has 12px radius too

Problem, the radius does not match.
I would like the part of the scroll bar that is outside of the modal to be hidden.

Here is a [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/hS0E8KKZq0)

Here is the test code :

```
<div class="h-screen w-screen bg-gray-300">
  <div class="fixed left-1/2 top-1/2 h-fit max-h-[70px] w-[200px] -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 overflow-y-scroll overflow-hidden rounded-xl bg-white p-3 text-center">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was is your expected behaviour? Do you want to just hide your scrollbar?

Comment: @PatrickCerny Hello. No, I need the scrollbar but I want the part of the scrollbar that is outside of the modal to be hidden

Comment: Ahh crap... wrote a whole answer and its wrong then :D Ah no, it should be ok?

Comment: Your answer is good ! I accept when SO allow me. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the content that needs to be scrolled in a `div` remove the classes `max-h-[70px] w-[200px] overflow-y-scroll` from parent and place in the new `div` class.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen w-screen bg-gray-300">
  <div class="fixed left-1/2 top-1/2 h-fit  -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2  overflow-hidden rounded-xl bg-white text-center">
    <div class="max-h-[70px] w-[200px] overflow-y-scroll">
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```